# Sample Geometric Mean and Sample Median of a Log-Normal Random Variable

Tags: median, lognormal-distribution, geometric-mean

The Wikipedia article for the log-normal distribution states that the geometric mean and median of a log-normal random variable are equal. However, when I simulate log normal data with a small N, sample estimates of the geometric mean and median are not equal. They appear to converge for large N.

```
set.seed(40)
# N = 50
log_x <- rnorm(50, mean = 2, sd = 2)
x <- exp(log_x)

(gmean <- exp(mean(log_x)))
(med <- median(x))


# N = 5000

log_x <- rnorm(5000, mean = 2, sd = 2)
x <- exp(log_x)

(gmean <- exp(mean(log_x)))
(med <- median(x))
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: The Wikipedia statement concerns the *distribution,* not samples from it!  Literally any finite batch of positive numbers *could* arise as a sample from a given Lognormal distribution, so you cannot expect most properties of the distribution to apply to all possible samples.

Comment: You will also find the mean and median of `log_x` differ though they will usually be close for large sample sizes, and all normal distributions have mean equal to median.  This is the same thing but as a power of $e$

Comment: @Henry The closeness of the mean and median depends on the shape parameter of the Lognormal, not the sample size.  Large sample size does not tend to make those two statistics close.

Comment: @whuber I was talking for the normal distribution about the sample mean and sample median, and for the lognormal about the sample geometric mean and the sample median, all of which converge in a suitable sense to the population equivalent as the sample size increases

Comment: @Henry Thank you for clearing up my confusion!